# React Native: how to simulate onBlur and onFocus event for View

Tags: react-native

In React Native, only `TextInput` has `onFocus` and `onBlur` event listener. However, we would like to simulate this effect on a `View`.

Here is what we try to achieve. There is a `View` on the screen. It gains "focus" when user taps on it and is hightlighted. We want to detect that user taps outside the `View`, so that we can "blur" the `View`, that is, remove the highlight.

I know we can use `focus` method (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemethodsmixin.html#focus) to request focus for the `View`. The problem is that I don't know how to detect that user presses outside the `View`.

Answer (score 7):

I think the easiest is to set a state variable instead so you can play with that one such as:

```
class MyView extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeView: null,
    }
    this.views = [
      (<View style={{ padding: 20 }}><Text>View 1</Text></View>),
      (<View style={{ padding: 20 }}><Text>View 2</Text></View>),
      (<View style={{ padding: 20 }}><Text>View 3</Text></View>),
      (<View style={{ padding: 20 }}><Text>View 4</Text></View>),
      (<View style={{ padding: 20 }}><Text>View 5</Text></View>),
    ];
  }

  _setActive( index ) {
    return () => {
      this.setState({ activeView: index })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
        {this.views.map( (view, index) => {
        let containerStyle = [];
        if ( index === this.state.activeView ) {
          containerStyle.push({ borderWidth: 10 })
        }
        return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._setActive(index)} style={containerStyle}>
          {view}
        </TouchableOpacity>
        );
        })}
      </View>
      );
  }
}
```

You can use `MyView` where requried as `<MyView />` also every item on the array `views` can have any style required and configure each if is active just by access to `this.state.activeView`.

Let me know if you have any question.

Answer (score 4):

In situations like this, I add `onPress()` to the the element that is outside of the `View` in question.

`<View onPress(removeHighlight)></View> 
<View onPress(addHighlight)></View>`